# Как сделать так, чтобы выводился отдельно текст женского пола и мужского? В один <p> - мужской ник, а в другой - женский

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function random() {

  var name1 = document.getElementById('name1')
  var name2 = document.getElementById('name2')

  var a = Math.round(Math.random() * 4)
  // это число должно совпадать с максимальным индексом таблицы ссылок

  txt = new Array();
  txt[0] = "Женский пол0"
  txt[1] = "Женский пол1"
  txt[2] = "Женский пол2"
  txt[3] = "Женский пол3"
  txt[4] = "Женский пол4"


  var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 4)
  // это число должно совпадать с максимальным индексом таблицы ссылок

  txt = new Array();
  txt[0] = "Женский пол0"
  txt[1] = "Мужской пол1"
  txt[2] = "Мужской пол2"
  txt[3] = "Мужской пол3"
  txt[4] = "Мужской пол4"
  // document.write (""+txt[a]+"");
  name1.innerHTML = ("" + txt[a] + "")
  name2.innerHTML = ("" + txt[b] + "")

}
```

```html
<p id="name1"></p>
<p id="name2"></p>
<button class="random" onclick="random()">Кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function random() {
  // это число должно совпадать с максимальным индексом таблицы ссылок
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
}

function func() {

  let name1 = document.getElementById('name1')
  let name2 = document.getElementById('name2')

  let men = ["Мужской пол0", "Мужской пол1", "Мужской пол2", "Мужской пол3", "Мужской пол4"]
  let women = ["Женский пол0", "Женский пол1", "Женский пол2", "Женский пол3", "Женский пол4"]

  name1.innerHTML = men[random()]
  name2.innerHTML = women[random()]

}
```

```html
<p id="name1"></p>
<p id="name2"></p>
<button class="func" onclick="func()">Кнопка</button>
```